# I cannot find the steel mill and the glue grenade?

Tags: batman-arkham-origins

I have read a lot about the steel mill and the glue grenade but I cannot find it. I need the glue grenade to get some data packs. Where can I find the steel mill and the glue grenade?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Glue Grenades aren't available until late in the game. They are given to you after you capture

> The Joker

as the main story progresses.

---

Sionis' Steel Mill is located in the Industrial District, but you won't be able to enter it until the main story requires you to, so finding it before then is not going to help.